# Count number of lines depending of criteria (similar to group by)

Tags: mysql

I am actually facing an issue with MySQL, I need to have a similar behavior of the GROUP BY but without grouping.

Here is an example for just one table named 'resident' with 2 columns: 'name', 'city'.

If i want to count the number residents for each city, i just need to do this :

```
SELECT resident.city, count(resident.name) as 'Nb residents'
FROM resident
GROUP BY resident.city
```

So the result would be like :

```
| city | Nb residents |
| NY   |       3      |
| HK   |       1      |
| Rome |       2      |
...
```

But i am looking for a way to display my result like that :

```
|   name   |  city  |  Nb residents |
| Name1    | NY     |       3       |
| Name2    | NY     |       3       |
| Name3    | NY     |       3       |
| Name4    | HK     |       1       |
| Name5    | Rome   |       2       |
| Name6    | Rome   |       2       |
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT resident.name, resident.city, (select count(a.name) from resident a where a.city = resident.city) as 'Nb residents'
FROM resident
```

Answer (score 2):

You could to this with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.`name`, t2.`city`, t3.`Nb residents`
FROM resident t1
JOIN ( SELECT resident.city, count(resident.name) as 'Nb residents' FROM resident GROUP BY resident.city ) t2
  ON t1.`city`= t2.`city`
```

This extracts the amount of residents per city in a subquery and then joins this with the names of the very table.